# C# - What does _ = do?

Tags: c#, constructor

Sorry for this noob question, but I could not find the info anywhere

I see many functions or constructor creating a task and assigning it to an undefined underscore variable

```
public SomeClass()
{
  _ = SomeTaskAsync();
```

I don't understand what does this do
is it a temp variable ? or something to avoid gc to do its job ?

thanks

[edit: sorry but I don't understand the point of using a variable if it is not used, underscore or not]

Comment: Tag your programming language.

Comment: In C# an underscore discards the value, it's syntax sugar for ignoring the result. Useful for making it clear you aren't interested in the output

Comment: If we are talking about C# then `_` means it's a discard. Discards are placeholder variables that are intentionally unused in application code.

Comment: thanks, my bad I went too fast, I adapted the question

Comment: why not just call "await SomeTaskAsync();" why the discard ?

Comment: To make it more explicit that the return value is not used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a point to using the C# discard operator for method return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984923/is-there-a-point-to-using-the-c-sharp-discard-operator-for-method-return-values)

Comment: "To make it more explicit that the return value is not used" sorry I may be a complete idiot and admit it, but I just don't get it. it is not used, why making it explicit ?

Comment: It looks like a constructor - you cannot use `await` there

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, _ discards intentionally an unused variable in the application code.

To dive into this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards

Comment: yes, now this makes more sense "( _ , _ , area) = city.GetCityInformation(cityName);" but not "_ = Function();"